# MySQL DataReader only read first row and nothing else

Tags: c#, datareader

I've been trying to read data from my table Employee (7 columns) with 3 employees registered, and DataReader just read first row (7 fields instead the total, 21 fields)

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetEmployees")]
public List<clsEmployee> GetEmployees()
{
    MySqlDataReader reader;
    List<clsEmployee> employees = new List<clsEmployee>();

    string strSQL = "SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.email, e.dni, e.phone, e.SpecialityID from Employee e";

    reader = CmdDatabase.GetReader(strSQL, configuration.GetConnectionString("da_adminsys"));

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        clsEmployee emp = new clsEmployee
        {
            EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]),
            FirstName = reader["firstname"].ToString(),
            LastName = reader["lastname"].ToString(),
            Email = reader["email"].ToString(),
            Phone = reader["phone"].ToString(),
            DNI = reader["dni"].ToString(),
            SpecialityID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["SpecialityID"]),
        };

        employees.Add(emp);
    }

    foreach (var item in employees)
    {
        clsSpeciality speciality = GetSpeciality(item.SpecialityID);
        item.Speciality.Add(speciality);
    }

    reader.Close();

    return employees;
}
```

And `GetReader` from my class `CmdDatabase`:

```cs
public static MySqlDataReader GetReader(string strQuery, string CN)
{
    MySqlConnection  oConnection = new MySqlConnection(CN);
    MySqlCommand oCommand = new MySqlCommand(strQuery, oConnection);
    oConnection.Open();
    MySqlDataReader oReader;

    oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    oCommand.Dispose();
    return oReader;
}
```

At the while loop its just counting 7 FieldCount, and totally in the table are 21 fields

Comment: You do not need the while loop if you are just reading one row : reader.Read() (no while)  Then just use use existing code to read the seven columns.

Comment: @jdweng im trying to read ALL the records, but idk why im getting just first row

Comment: It seems odd to call `oCommand.Dispose();` before you have read anything. Have you tried doing the same thing but not using `GetReader` and instead opening the connection via `using` statments? For example e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#examples. This way you could debug and see exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this wrong, as you are disposing the command before finshing reading from the reader.

You need to have the conenction, command and reader all in `using`.

```cs
public List<clsEmployee> GetEmployees()
{
    var employees = GetEmployeesFromDb(configuration.GetConnectionString("da_adminsys"));

    foreach (var item in employees)
    {
        clsSpeciality speciality = GetSpeciality(item.SpecialityID);
        item.Speciality.Add(speciality);
    }

    return employees;
}

public static List<clsEmployee> GetEmployeesFromDb(string connectionString)
{
    const string strSQL = @"
SELECT
  e.EmployeeID,
  e.FirstName,
  e.LastName,
  e.email,
  e.dni,
  e.phone,
  e.SpecialityID
from Employee e;
";

    using var oConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    using var oCommand = new MySqlCommand(strQuery, oConnection);
    oConnection.Open();
    using var oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader();
    var employees = new List<clsEmployee>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        clsEmployee emp = new clsEmployee
        {
            EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]),
            FirstName = reader["firstname"].ToString(),
            LastName = reader["lastname"].ToString(),
            Email = reader["email"].ToString(),
            Phone = reader["phone"].ToString(),
            DNI = reader["dni"].ToString(),
            SpecialityID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["SpecialityID"]),
        };

        employees.Add(emp);
    }
    return employees;
}
```

I have no idea what your `GetSpeciality` does, but if it's a database call then you are much better off using a single database call with a join.

---

Also consider using `async` especially given that this is in the middle of an ASP.Net HTTP request. That would look like this

```
public async Task<List<clsEmployee>> GetEmployees()
{
    var employees = await GetEmployeesFromDb(configuration.GetConnectionString("da_adminsys"));

    foreach (var item in employees)
    {
        clsSpeciality speciality = GetSpeciality(item.SpecialityID);
        item.Speciality.Add(speciality);
    }

    return employees;
}

public static async Task<List<clsEmployee>> GetEmployeesFromDb(string connectionString)
{
    const string strSQL = @"
SELECT
  e.EmployeeID,
  e.FirstName,
  e.LastName,
  e.email,
  e.dni,
  e.phone,
  e.SpecialityID
from Employee e;
";

    using var oConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    using var oCommand = new MySqlCommand(strQuery, oConnection);
    await oConnection.OpenAsync();
    using var oReader = await oCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    var employees = new List<clsEmployee>();

    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        clsEmployee emp = new clsEmployee
        {
            EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]),
            FirstName = reader["firstname"].ToString(),
            LastName = reader["lastname"].ToString(),
            Email = reader["email"].ToString(),
            Phone = reader["phone"].ToString(),
            DNI = reader["dni"].ToString(),
            SpecialityID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["SpecialityID"]),
        };

        employees.Add(emp);
    }
    return employees;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, that was the solution. It's now working, but I have another issue. When the data is being read, It's reading data from a table where the corresponding records have already been deleted, but the "get" operation still shows them. The same thing happens when I try to insert data; it doesn't appear to affect the database, although it does impact the ID because it shows that new IDs are being created. Even though a "select * from employees" doesn't display it, when performing a delete on, for example, ID 12, the result is "1 row affected."

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the right database?

Comment: Forget it, the mentioned errors were resolved by restarting MySQL Workbench (almost one week opened) . I don't know exactly why, but everything is working! Again, thank you very much!